# Use Variable In PHP Query

Tags: php

I need to execute this query in my php code.  My issue is that I have never run a query that uses a variable as part of it.  This is my code, i do not get any results returned or an error.  Where did I miss up?

```
$userID = getFields('users', JFactory::getUser(), true); 
$db->setQuery("SELECT rep_id, inventory_id, value 
               FROM #data 
               WHERE inventory_id_id = 1 
               AND rep_id = " $userID ");
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: Do you really have table named `#data`?

Comment: no, i changed it for example sake

Comment: This is not how you concatenate strings in PHP. You use the `.` (period) symbol.

Also note that injecting a variable straight into a query is very dangerous and susceptible to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). I'd highly recommend switching to [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a period to concatenate strings in PHP.

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT rep_id, inventory_id, value 
               FROM #data 
               WHERE inventory_id_id = 1 
               AND rep_id = " . $userID);
```

Also, please note that your code is open to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). I'd highly recommend switching to [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @HotTomales there is literally no way for me to know that I'm afraid since I have no clue what the `getFields` function does in this case.

Comment: Ah, understood.  And no quotes needed around the 1?

Comment: Not if it's not a string! :) Single quotes are used to wrap strings in SQL. @HotTomales